# How can I use the querybuilder with choice label in formbuilder?

Tags: php, symfony, query-builder, formbuilder

I am using the formbuilder querybuilder with choice label:

```
 $options['query_builder'] = function (EntityRepository $er) use ($fieldId) {
        $output = $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC');
        return $output;
 };

 $options['choice_label'] = 'category';
```

It works very well, also when I try to get the name instead:

```
 $options['choice_label'] = 'name';
```

But what I would need is a combination of both in my dropdown, but still keep the ordering.

```
   $options['choice_label'] = 'category -> name';
```

I cannot figure out how to do that. I am grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'choice_label' can also be used with a function ([docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-label)).

```
'choice_label' => function (Category $category) {
    return $category->getId() . ' -> ' . $category->getName();
}
```

to order the results by category name this should work:

```
'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($fieldId) {
    $output = $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->join('c.category', 'ca')
        ->orderBy('ca.name', 'ASC')
        ->addOrderBy('c.name', 'ASC');
    return $output;
 };
```

Comment: Yes I tried that before, but no one could help me to do an ordering with this variation -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63120365/how-can-i-order-sort-in-a-formbuilder-choice-label-function Do you know how to do that?

Comment: 'choice_label' does not affect ordering at all. I think you should use 'group_by' => function ($entity) { $entity->getCategory->getName() } https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#group-by

Comment: Do you happen to know how to sort the groups?

Comment: I think you need to adjust inside query_builder. I'll add it to my answer.